# Include foreign keys in Mysql table creation or link tables in php application?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Before creating a database for a potential PHP/Mysql application, I was looking at my tables in MySql Workbench and noticed the option to include a foreign key when building each table.

Should I declare the foreign keys in the SQL statements that build the tables when I create the database?  Or... should I just link the tables in the SQL select and insert statements in my PHP pages?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

First learn what is the significance of a foreign key constraints.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

And Besides I always believe **Work in your DB harder to Code lesser**

Answer (score 0):

In every database I have analyzed that lack foreign key constraints, the data is messed up.  Rows exist in child tables that reference rows that have been deleted in the parent table.

These "orphan" rows are hard to prevent, and even hard to detect, if you have no foreign key constraints.  You basically have to rely on writing perfect code in your application -- that's a risky thing to depend on!  ;-)

I wrote about how to automate detection of orphan rows here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/18/eventual-consistency-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should try to write the correct application code *and* have foreign keys in the database.

Foreign keys are one of the most important ways to ensure the integrity of data (they essentially protect from dangling pointers<sup>1</sup>). This is pretty much the only correct *and* performant way to do it in a concurrent environment.

Relying *only* on the application logic to always write the correct data is fragile<sup>2</sup>. The database itself should defend itself from bad data as much as possible, primarily through the declarative integrity constraints<sup>3</sup>, and possibly through non-declarative means<sup>4</sup> as well.

---

*<sup>1</sup> I'm using the word "pointer" loosely here.*

*<sup>2</sup> A bug in even one of the applications that write to the database can put the data in peril. If several clients try to write the related data concurrently, hard-to-catch race conditions may occur; locking would likely be necessary, impacting the scalability.*

*<sup>3</sup> Integrity of domain (type system and CHECK constraints), integrity of key (PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints) and referential integrity (FOREIGN KEY constraints).*

*<sup>4</sup> Such as triggers and stored procedures.*